# SwiftUI update LocalizedStringResource interpolated value after change of environment(\.locale

Tags: swiftui, locale, string-catalog

I'm trying to change a locale on a fly, but it doesn't work for interpolated strings:

```
//this struct is mandatory
struct Constants {
    static let download = LocalizedStringResource("Download", table: "General")
    static let items = LocalizedStringResource("%lld item", table: "General")
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var language: String = "uk"

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle().foregroundStyle(.white)
            VStack {

                Text(Constants.download)
                Text(String(format: String(localized:Constants.items), 13))
                
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            language = (language == "en") ? "uk" : "en"
        }
        .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: language))
        .id(language) //try to force reload UI..
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Also, please note, if you change a **scheme language** parameter:

[image]

Then it will load string and interpolation **will work** for **selected** language:

[image]

But after that, still, changing a locale doesn't update language value with interpolation.

Looks like a SwiftUI internal logic problem? Or is there maybe could be some workaround for this?

My General.xcstrings translated:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `String(localized:)` doesn't care about SwiftUI's environment. It only looks at the locale of the `LocalizedStringResource`, which will be the system locale.

Rather than `static let`s in `Constants`, you should make the interpolated strings *functions*, so that you can format them in place:

```
static func items(_ n: Int) -> LocalizedStringResource {
    LocalizedStringResource("\(n) Items", table: "General")
}
```

Usage:

```
Text(Constants.items(13))
```

This work because you are directly giving the resource to `Text`, and `Text` can localise it using SwiftUI's environment.

I'm not sure why you are using `LocalizedStringResource` instead of `LocalizedStringKey`. Unless you do need specific functionalities from `LocalizedStringResource`, use `LocalizedStringKey` instead.

Comment: thanks! It works! The idea of using LocalizedStringResource is to use a 'table:' param, so I can group my strings into separate '.xcstrings' files.

Comment: @KAMIKAZE I see. You can do that without `LocalizedStringResource` too - you just have to pass the `table:` to `Text`. But I guess you might not like that...

Comment: Yep, my main idea is - collect all text strings into a one file, also make groups.. but not just all text strings places all around SwiftUI code in a whole project)

Comment: @KAMIKAZE: As an addition to this great answer, might I suggest my build tool plugin, [xcstrings-tool](https://github.com/liamnichols/xcstrings-tool) that can generate the correct Swift code for you to make working with multiple catalogs really simple

Comment: @liamnichols that xcstrings-tool is overcomplicated.. I just created a `struct Constants {' where I have all strings as 'static let download = Localized("Download", table: "General")` and I can use it in my `Text(Constants.download)`  just like that... and now I just added a `func` as Sweeper suggested. Thats it.

Comment: Yeah that’s fine, it’s the same code at the end of the day. The plugin just has some conveniences that help maintain consistency and help you save some time when scaling things up 